# Debugging Only Obj-C/C in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

Now that I've upgraded to Lion and Xcode 4.3.x, the debugger is stepping into the ARC stuff. So I'm seeing a screen full of

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue:
0x1de7fe0:  pushl  %ebp
```

and `pushl` and `movl` and `subl` etc. Unfortunately I cannot symbolicate these, nor do I care to debug Apple's stuff. Is there any way to get the debugger to focus ONLY on code I actually have in my possession?

I'm using LLDB but the same thing happens with GDB.

**EDIT:** This happens on AppCode too, which says something (but I don't know what).

Comment: +1 I would love to see a way around this sort of behavior. Similar assembly stepping problems have been happening for me for years (though I think it may be related to working with Adobe's SDKs), and I usually have to step over a couple instructions before I can step out and end up in the proper source file again. Very frustrating!

Comment: @inspector-g in AppCode it's a bit less annoying, I think, and I'm beginning to grow a bit fonder of their debugger now. It does have the same problem, however. Anyway, let's hope for an answer here...

Comment: I agree. Apple has really dropped the ball with debugging in Xcode.

Comment: @EvanMulawski let's hope it's not ARC that they've dropped the ball on.

Comment: @Yar, ARC actually works really well. I've been using it for a while, and except in very rare situations (usually when I'm doing something that I shouldn't be), it has worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Hi @JRG-Developer, glad to hear it. This question was about a bug that has since been fixed in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't what you want to hear, but as of Xcode 4.5.2 (the current version of Xcode, or at least the most current I have ;), I don't believe it's possible to have the debugger automatically skip over Apple's internal instructions. I don't believe this is related to ARC in particular, but just how the latest version of the debugger is working.

Here's ways I've gotten around this while debugging:

1) You can use the "skip over" button to continue onto the next piece of code (and you may have to do this a few times to get out of Apple's stuff).

2) You can put a breakpoint right before and right after your code that you're debugging. This way, instead of using the skip over button, you can use the "play" button.

Comment: we don't have this problem anymore. This question is obsolete. Thanks!

Comment: If that's the case, please answer the question yourself and let us know what you did to solve the problem, or accept one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ARC yet, but I remember reading this which may have some clues on configuring the debugger that might help:

http://brian-webster.tumblr.com/post/20941658970/debugging-an-arc-mac-application-on-snow-leopard

Comment: thanks for that. not sure how to evaluate whether it's relevant or not. doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

While the message you've posted is ARC-related, this behavior has nothing to do with ARC; something's just dropping the debugger down into the assembly instructions.  Using the Step Out button in the debugger is actually what you want to pull you back into your own code.